# Can you please recommend a Daf Yomi app that reads the full page before commentary? Or Talmud audio app in general

Tags: talmud-gemara, daf-yomi

I am not doing a Daf Yomi cycle specifically, but I want to shift my focus more back to Gemara than what I've been studying mostly the last few years. However, I want some audio help this time to lessen the reading load. So I looked for Daf Yomi apps but many of them are taking hours to cover one page before even getting to discuss with companions yourself, because they are reading one sentence in Hebrew, then in english, then the Rabbi speaking gives explanations in his own words, then he goes to the next sentence in Hebrew, then english, then explanations.

Can you please recommend an app where they are just reading the full page from Artscroll or Koren Talmud without interruption, and then a shiurim on it afterwards, or an app that has separate videos for both? I know Artscroll already  has lots of notes, references, and explanations in their text itself. It's 73 volumes already, so just an uninterrupted reading covers a lot. Koren is not quite as long but also reads well as is. I would prefer audio that is just reading page by page of either Artscroll or Koren Talmud, uninterrupted, and then if I still need more study for given pages, I could click the shiur separately for that page.

Toda raba. And I really appreciate all the help given here.

Comment: You're probably not going to find a read-through of Artscroll or Koren, for copyright reasons.

Comment: @magicker72 What are they reading in the english Daf Yomi podcasts? Or is it legal to read them if you intersperse commentary in between sentences? I'd settle for any intelligible english translation being read but those would be preferable.

Comment: @magicker72 Isn't the koren english already free on sefaria? if so a non-commercial reading could be ok (cyloL)

Comment: https://www.dafyomi.org/download.php?masechta=brachos

Comment: Thanks Ezra. I actually came across that one when I looked. It works but ideally I am still hoping to find a better fit. The Rabbi is still reading every verse in Hebrew first, which cuts what I can learn per a measure in time in half by itself, and the audio quality is not the easiest to listen to.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct reading of an Artscroll, but Rabbi Shloime Schwarzberg's [Daf HaChaim](https://dafhachaim.org/) is the most straight reading of the Daf I've ever heard - he's pure translation and explanation, nothing more, nothing less. You can even often go through the Rashi word for word sometimes as he speaks it out outside in English.

Comment: Thank you. This is the best I've seen so far but its still 34 minutes for Berachos 2, whereas even the longer Artscroll version took me maybe half that time to read, maybe one third.I dont want to come off picky, but let's say it normally takes you four years to read the Talmud start to finish. Well now it takes eight years, or twelve years, if you see what I mean. That extra 50% to 67% of time per Daf adds up to years  worth of extra study time. If I was fluent in Hebrew, I'd want Hebrew only Daf except for when necessary, and for english speakers, Hebrew only for names, word similarities etc

Comment: I do appreciate shiurim where Hebrew is used frequently, even tho I cant understand. And prayers of course. Its spiritually powerful. But the Talmud is so long, to read every sentence in both languages is not what I'd prefer, because of how much time it takes away that I could be learning and understanding it. I have no idea if I'm in the minority in that, if others believe Talmud should not be read period without the Hebrew either on the page, or vocalized, in which case, this double-time issue is unique to audio format because with both languages printed on page I still only read the english

Comment: Although it's worth noting, @ShipBuilding, that even if you were completely fluent in Hebrew you'd still need a translation of the Gemarra, as it's written in Aramaic.

Comment: Definitely, thank you for noting that. Basically, if I were fluent in Hebrew, I would want it read only in Hebrew, not one sentence in Aramaic first, then Hebrew translation, then Aramaic for the next sentence, then Hebrew translation. Or not english and then Hebrew for most of the Mishnah. I'd like to get through ten pages per day not one page per day, and at 34 mins per daf that means over 5 hours of study per day, for 10 pages.

Comment: @ShipBuilding I suppose you should think first a bit about how gemara learning goes. By such reading you describe you wouldn't hardly understand anything, and in my view it would be a waste of time. Daf yomi shiurim are already very condensed, usually they're at the edge of comprehensibility. Try first learning an easier tractate like Berakhot or Megillah, get a taste of it, and then you could make a more informed decision whether your idea still made sense.

Comment: Check: hadran.org.il There is still Aramaic reading, but most of what you'll hear is English. Very clear for beginners (for women, by women) and very relatable too, thus making the content covered easier to remember.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I have the Artscroll  and that's what I always read from. I'm sure I missed some things but the more something covers the more time it takes to learn. You bring up a good point about what the right balance is, and I certainly do not know the best balance. My problem is with my memory I am forgetting even some of the more basic dafs, and lots of the halachah specifics, lots of entire pages of just the text itself. So I would like to go through it again as fast as possible relatively speaking because I don't have that memorized let alone extra context and explanations. But maybe it's

Comment: @Kazibácsi worth the extra time for me even at this stage. However my concern is that in twice the time as reading Artscroll in one language, the Rabbi is actually covering a _less_  because he's speaking in two languages, and giving explanations in real time, with pauses to think of the best word to use and stuff like that, rather than the pre-written Artscroll or Koren which edited every word to the best of their ability before publishing.

Comment: @user16403 Thank you. Great audio quality. Explanations seem very good. Length is not short but there are plus sides to that. Still holding out to find something similar to a reading of artscroll Talmud in english, but it may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try quick daf from Zecharia Resnik ,most dafim are around 7- 15 minute range which is a word for word reading of gemara and incorporates Rashi's pshat frequently.

https://www.thequickdaf.com/

Comment: Keep in mind Yevamos will have a 20 min shiur just due to the diffuclt content

Comment: Ty Sam. This is also good and something I could use. I would also like one that is referencing whichever commentaries are relevant to each line of each Daf at that time, whether Rashi or not. I know that's subjective which to use when, but I like the way Artscroll did it.

Comment: Basically I just want to spend my time learning the authorative sources. If the Rabbi doing the Daf is quoting commentaries he thinks are relevant, that's great, but if he is thinking what to say and explaining mostly in his own words, that can be good but can also mean less time I could be learning what everyone from Rambam to the Gra wrote. I'd rather learn their teachings first, and then in the unlikely event I'm still alive by the time I learned all the teachings of the many Rabbonim and sages etc etc, I'll have time to learn the explanations of the Rabbi doing the Daf _at that point_

Comment: Although assuredly, he is likely learned in most of their teachings and may have unique insights, as well as modern insights and lessons. So it's definitely a tricky balance. And I'm not saying a modern Rabbi's teachings could not be just as important, or making any sort of negative comparison between one or the other. I respect them all. All I mean to say is I only have so much time, so I would rather learn as much from the classic sources as possible first. I'd like 90% of the Daf to be either reading directly from Talmud, or reading directly from one of the Rabbonim or sages etc, in english

Comment: Hos daf is very similar to Artscroll in that he translates the text and explains basically using Rashi's pshat. When you read artscroll the bold text is translation while the unbolded text is really rashi's explanation

Comment: When needed they have notes from whatever sources necessary. I still wish they had more Kabbalist notes, and covered the full range of opinions on each issue. It would be super long but at least I am learning from the sages writings first hand. I dont know if there is any text like that but I would be interested in a text that includes the full canon of midrash since matan Torah, but for brevity's sake leaves out similar opinions from multiple sources, but includes every single unique interpretation let's say, from everyone from Moshe to the Rebbe. But that may not exist (most likely).

Comment: It's not a problem to look up each unique opinion in different texts if you already know which Rabbis had unique opinions on each verse and each issue, and what page of what text they are in, but if you don't already know then it makes it difficult. You read one text without having any idea another Rabbi had a totally different interpretation, until you get learning that text ten years later, by which time you've half forgotten the first opinion. I need some sort of table of contents or interlinking reference for the entire midrash "canon" to help my studies. Not sure if that exists either.

Comment: Note, I consider every Rabbi's opinion "unique," even in cases where they have a very similar opinion to many other Rabbis, or on issues where there is not much disagreement or discussion. I am just limited by language and "unique" was the closest word I know in english. I meant that I wish artscroll or another text would always alert u about any case where a Rabbi or sage had a differnt opinion that stands out, or inform u of all the existing peshat, remez, derash, and sod opinions for each gemara and each verse in Tanakh and each halachah, all in 1 text or reference guide, to orient learning

Comment: This class: https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/talmud.htm does bring in sod concepts with frequency, you may want to check it out

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently using the app real clear daf so I can listen to Torah while I work and also when I exercise. I'm not sure it meets your question exactly in this order but it is straight forward and doesn't take too long to cover the daf. So far the typical time ranges from 30 minutes to an hour depending on the page. So far I am enjoying the shiurim very much and recommend it. It's great for a "b'kius" overview of the daf.